# MaterializeCSS bunching multiple choice menu together

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, materialize

I am using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com) and seem to have a weird issue with one of my Menus that was previously working. Here is was it is currently doing, 
[image]

The underlying code is a loop.

```
 <div class="input-field col s6">
                <select id="keywords" name="Keywords" multiple>

                    <%
                        Dim SQLQuery As String, IBResults As ADODB.Recordset
                        'get all the project keywords
                        SQLQuery = "SELECT APK.* " & "FROM Avail_Project_Keywords APK " & "WHERE APK.KeywordID <> 0 " & "ORDER BY APK.Description ASC;"

                        IBResults = GetBWRS("Infobase", SQLQuery)
                        If Not IBResults.EOF Then
                            Do Until IBResults.EOF
                                Response.Write("<option value='" & DBStr(IBResults.Fields("KeywordID")) & "'>")
                                Response.Write(DBStr(IBResults.Fields("Description")))
                                Response.Write("</option>")
                                IBResults.MoveNext()
                            Loop
                        End If



                    %>
                </select>
                <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
            </div>
```

With the standard js caller on the bottom

```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
            var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
        });
```

Am I doing something wrong here? If so what is the problem. It matches the example code and when I compare the two with inspect element everything seem to be the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the Materialize CSS documentation, `<select>` needs to have this as the basic initialization. You seem to have missed out the options parameter.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
});
```

The HTML seems fine.

Comment: options aren't required, adding the word options will just break it unless I tell it something like `(elems, {classes: "myClassChoice"})`

Comment: Can you put a sample as a fiddle? Assessing the problem becomes easier then.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,@Lankymart I am only querying anything with `<select>` tags the segment of code contains the <option> tags in the vba.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thanks to those who tried to help out. It was appreciated.

I ended up downloading a new fresh copy of the Framework out of frustration. Now everything is working as expected. It probably will not help anyone who suffers this in the future unfortunately.

I am not sure why this fixed it. So if you are having this problem. Do try either linking their CDN's or downloading a fresh copy for yourself.